# Type annotation in match pattern

Tags: types, rust, annotations, match

I'm using the `serde_json` crate and have to make a type annotation for the return value of `serde_json::from_slice()`. If I use a `let` and a `match` statement afterwards, this works

```
let n: Result<serde_json::Value, serde_json::Error> = serde_json::from_slice(buf);
match n {
    Ok(_i) => (),
    Err(_e) => (),
};
```

But as I don't need `n`, I don't want to make the `let` statement in the first place, and only use a single match pattern. How can I make the type annotation for `_i`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the [type parameters of a function call](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/gen_fn.html) by using this syntax `func::<T>()`.

In the case of [`from_slice()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.60/serde_json/fn.from_slice.html), you only need to specify the success value type. So all you need is `from_slice::<Value>(buf)`.

```rust
match serde_json::from_slice::<serde_json::Value>(buf) {
    Ok(_i) => (),
    Err(_e) => (),
};
```